# Restoring Localhost Home page in php myadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

i used NetBeans to create a php project, but unfortunately i created that project in root folder that is "www" so i am unable to view my original version of homepage (index.php). I just want to view localhost as home page.is there any possibility for recovering it using windows 7 os or anything. i just deleted project using netbeans but its not restored.

Comment: on reinstalling wamp its installing as wampserver 2 and not repairing previous one

Comment: I you have replcaed default index.php then simple solution can only be install phpmyadmin elsewhere and simply copy paste that default index.php to replace the newly created. If you have not replaced the original index.php. Then you can have other ways as well. But my previously told solution is not that much difficult as well i think

Comment: ya reinstalling  is working fine thank you very much @sami,@asprin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments and question it seems you have replaced original index.php in the www directory with a new one and you are using WAMP.

Solution1: (Only If you want to save your databases then Copy your data folder from `wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24` and paste somewhere)

1.UnInstall WAMP. 2.Delete WAMP Folder 3. Reinstall it. (Put the data folder in same folder replacing the new one)

Solution 2: Install wamp elsewhere (better on other machine) and simply copy paste the genuine index.php from wamp/www to your wamp/www

Comment: @sampat... You could still read my answer to tackle same thing in future. Specially saving data becomes problem. As it has been with me :)

Comment: oh good answer @sami, i just taking backup into an sql file and by doing the above procedure it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 you have the ability to 'Restore to a previous version' for seperate files and folders. You might try to right-click on the folder and click 'Restore previous versions'. If that doesn't work, I think there's no way back.

Comment: yes i checked for previous versions but reinstalling it working fine.thanks for your answer.@Thijmen

Comment: Oi Thijmen, you're the messiah!